# iOS App Memory profiling

Tags: ios, profiling, instruments

I've got an issue with my iOS app getting exponentially slower to respond to tap gestures.

It's an alphabet game so cycles through a list of 26 pictures.

Using instruments, it looks like the memory footprint is healty at ~6-7 Mb:

[image: Instruments allocations]

Update: 
Here is a shot of my running app in profiler.. it looks hungry - real memory usage (blue line) in the 300 - 500 Mb range..

[image]

I've not profiled before and find the Instruments app quite unintuitive. Can someone give me a high level pointer to get me started on narrowing this down?

Comment: Any chance the 26 pictures are displayed using a page control and UIScrollView ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. I'd suggest watching WWDC 2012 video, [Learning Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=409).
2. The WWDC 2010 video, [Advanced Memory Analysis with Instuments](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/?id=311) might focus more just on memory. There might be superficial UI changes in Instruments over the last few years that it doesn't reflect, but the concepts and ideas are still applicable.
3. The use of zombies is wonderful for finding over released items where you might have dangling pointers. This is incredibly useful in manual reference counting (MRC, i.e. you have ARC turned off), but of less value in automatic reference counting (ARC) world. It achieves this by keeping track of "released" memory. But it actually consumes memory to achieve this. I'd suggest turning off zombies once you have resolved your over-release problem, otherwise you'll see memory not be returned to the app as quickly as you otherwise would have.
4. Especially if you are not using ARC, check out the static analyzer (press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> or choose "Analyze" on the "Product" menu). This identifies many routine memory management mistakes.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using ARC. I will prob check the WWDC video as I really need some fundamental idea of how to track down the issue that doesn't look logic related but design related. Updated with a different instruments view.

Comment: There are a ton of WWDC videos that illustrate various Instruments techniques. These are just two that leaped out at me. I'd also suggest that [WWDC 2012 - iOS App Performance: Memory](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=242) also includes some practical demonstrations in the latter part of the video. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn off NSZombieEnabled.

Go to your scheme, and in the run configuration go to Diagnostics and make sure Enable Zombie Objects box is unchecked.